# Google not returning an international version of the page

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers

I run a website that duplicates some content across international editions. These are differentiated by the country codes e.g.

- `/uk/folder/article1/`
- `/au/folder/article1/`

The UK version is considered the origin of the content.

Recently the UK version of a specific article is being indexed by Google as I am able to access via keyword search, however when I try to search for it via: 
`site:domain.com/uk/folder/article1/` then it is not displaying, however the AU version is. Identical articles in the same folder are not having this issue.

There are no errors within webmaster tools and I have recently refetched the specific URL.

The main reason why this is problematic is because the article is now no longer appearing on the UK edition of the site for internal site search.

How can I find out why Google is not getting a result when the URL is entered but it is coming up when doing a specific keyword search?

Comment: Are your articles duplicated in more than one place?? If so, you need to pick one and use a canonical tag to point to just one. Here is some info: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Look for the header *Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element* for an example.

Comment: Yes they are. We use an SEO agency who said it shouldn't be an issue as we are clearly identifying the difference between /uk and /au. Would implementing the canonical tag affect internal site search that uses Google for the AU edition of the site?

Comment: If the pages are duplicate, using /uk and /au does not solve that problem. Essentially, using the canonical tag says to Google that *this one* is the original. I am not sure how it would effect your internal site search. If you are using Google SE (search engine) for internal search, I suspect it would return the original document if hreflang is not used. If the pages hreflang is set to en-uk and en-au, then I rather suspect that Google will maintain the users language preference. Here is Google page on that: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your response, really helpful. One question, on webmaster tools when checking for internal links to the UK and AU edition of the article, I am getting internal links for the AU edition of the article however no internal links for the UK edition of the article. What might this be a sign of?

Comment: Not sure. But please know that list is never complete- at least it has never been complete for me. I do not take this list too seriously.